# I2C bus linux: Systems with more than 4 memory slots not supported yet, not instantiating SPD

Tags: linux, memory, debian, i2c, motherboard

### Problem:

I believe there are enough motherboards with 8 memory slots.
I would like to see the contents of the SPD memory slots via decode-dimms, but
there is only support for up to 4 slots in the Linux kernel I2C bus, inclusive.

### Description:

Motherboard Asus P9X79pro 2011 year 8 memory slots

Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-2-amd64 (SMP w/8 CPU threads)

#### /etc/modules-load.d/:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
# we use any of the following three to choose for: eeprom at24 ee1004
at24
i2c_i801
i2c_smbus
i2c-dev
```

#### # i2cdetect -l

```
i2c-0   smbus       SMBus I801 adapter at f000          SMBus adapter
i2c-1   i2c         nvkm-0000:01:00.0-bus-0000          I2C adapter
i2c-2   i2c         nvkm-0000:01:00.0-bus-0001          I2C adapter
i2c-3   i2c         nvkm-0000:01:00.0-bus-0002          I2C adapter
```

#### /var/log/messages

```
[    1.349519] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: SMBus using PCI interrupt
[    1.350413] i2c i2c-0: 8/8 memory slots populated (from DMI)
[    1.350416] i2c i2c-0: Systems with more than 4 memory slots not supported yet, not instantiating SPD
```

#### # decode-dimms

```
# for 4.2-2+b1
No EEPROM found, the kernel probably does not support your hardware.
```

#### # decode-dimms

```
# decode-dimms version 4.3

Memory Serial Presence Detect Decoder
By Philip Edelbrock, Christian Zuckschwerdt, Burkart Lingner,
Jean Delvare, Trent Piepho and others


Number of SDRAM DIMMs detected and decoded: 0
```

#### # dmidecode:

```
Handle 0x002E, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x002C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA_Dimm1
    Bank Locator: ChannelA
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 4C0F1E75
    Asset Tag: ChannelA_Dimm1_AssetTag
    Part Number: KHX1600C10D3/8G
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x002C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA_Dimm2
    Bank Locator: ChannelA
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 360D8537
    Asset Tag: ChannelA_Dimm2_AssetTag
    Part Number: 9905403-558.A00LF
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s

Handle 0x0032, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x002C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB_Dimm1
    Bank Locator: ChannelB
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 4B0F776E
    Asset Tag: ChannelB_Dimm1_AssetTag
    Part Number: KHX1600C10D3/8G
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s

Handle 0x0034, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x002C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB_Dimm2
    Bank Locator: ChannelB
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 370DA637
    Asset Tag: ChannelB_Dimm2_AssetTag
    Part Number: 9905403-558.A00LF
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s

Handle 0x0036, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x002C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelC_Dimm1
    Bank Locator: ChannelC
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 1731AE49
    Asset Tag: ChannelC_Dimm1_AssetTag
    Part Number: KHX1600C10D3/8G
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s

Handle 0x0038, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x002C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelC_Dimm2
    Bank Locator: ChannelC
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 370D9537
    Asset Tag: ChannelC_Dimm2_AssetTag
    Part Number: 9905403-558.A00LF
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s

Handle 0x003A, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x002C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelD_Dimm1
    Bank Locator: ChannelD
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 1C31AE49
    Asset Tag: ChannelD_Dimm1_AssetTag
    Part Number: KHX1600C10D3/8G
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s

Handle 0x003C, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x002C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelD_Dimm2
    Bank Locator: ChannelD
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 360D9637
    Asset Tag: ChannelD_Dimm2_AssetTag
    Part Number: 9905403-558.A00LF
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s
```

#### linux-source-5.15/drivers/i2c/i2c-smbus.c

```
line 358:
    if (slot_count > 4) {
        dev_warn(&adap->dev,
             "Systems with more than 4 memory slots not supported yet, not instantiating SPD\n");
        return;
    }
```

### Houp:

Can someone suggest how to reach the kernel developers?

Answer (score 0):

A good place to read about the way Linux Kernel development works is https://kernelnewbies.org/ site. For more information how to reach kernel developers, you could read the [FoundBug subpage](https://kernelnewbies.org/FoundBug).

In this particular case, you could find a developer who wrote/maintains this code and contact him directly with your request. All kernel development is done in open so you can find the patch submission for example on [patchwork](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/linux-i2c/patch/20191118102741.794187d4@endymion/)

As you can see there, the patches were signed off by Jean Delvare, who happens to be the maintainer for most of the I2C/SMBus controller drivers in Linux, as can be seen in [maintainers list](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/maintainers.html#i2c-smbus-controller-drivers-for-pc).

Contacting the developer directly is not the only possibility. Probably the better choice would be to use a proper mailing list, which, again, can be found in the mainainters list linked above.

That being said, the fact *you can* reach kernel developers like that, does not mean **you should**, unless of course, you want to propose the patch yourself.